# Cannot see drive when trying to factory reset

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd

I'm currently trying to factory reset my 2015 macbook pro, but when I start it up, click cmd+r and try to erase it from disk utility, it doesn't show up. I also tried doing a `diskutil list` command, and my main hard drive wasn't listed on there. When I ran the same command on a normal boot, it was listed.

One important thing to note is that I installed an aftermarket SSD since my old Apple one was too small. Could that have something to do with it?

Overall, I'm not too sure why it's not showing up in the boot screen. Anyone have any idea why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS was on it last?

Comment: @Tetsujin Big Sur 11.2

Comment: Try Internet Recovery - Cmd/Opt/R

Comment: Giving it a shot right now

Comment: @Tetsujin alright - just reset my hard drives and got a question mark folder persisting so I'm following this guide to fix that up now: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204323